# Alexa Custom Skill Device Discovery

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am new to Alexa skill set, I have a device which needs to be discovered by alexa. I'm confused by the device discovery functionality of Alexa SMART HOME SKILL API. I need some detailed information about how to connect a device which built by you (using raspberry pie) to let Alexa discover through Custom skill.

sample code or good guidelines is needed.

I understand the payload should be returned from device cloud (product manufacturer owns this). How do you ensure which device is with customer and the device is of correct customer?

Example payload is below..

```
"discoveredAppliances": [{
    "applianceId": "sample-1",
    "manufacturerName": "Sample Manufacturer",
    "modelName": "Sample Thermostat",
    "version": "1",
    "friendlyName": "Sample Thermostat",
    "friendlyDescription": "Thermostat by Sample Manufacturer",
    "isReachable": true,
     "actions": [
        "setTargetTemperature",
        "incrementTargetTemperature",
        "decrementTargetTemperature"
     ],
     "additionalApplianceDetails": {
     "extraDetail1": "This is a thermostat that is reachable"
    }
 }]
```

Can you explain the discoveredAppliances json object in detail? the logic behind generating these details for customer in device cloud?

Answer (score 0):

All the information in the payload is for you to tell Alexa about your device, and can be whatever you want. The really important fields are:

- applianceId: must not contain spaces, and will be passed to your skill along with each control message. So make it something that identifies TO YOU the specific device.
- friendlyName: contains the exact words that a user will need to say to identify this device; for example, "garage light".

  - friendlyDescription: is the text that will be displayed in the Alexa app about this device.
  - actions: list the control events that you can handle. The example you list contains thermostat type controls. A light might support turnOn, turnOff, and possibly setPercentage for dimming.

How you detect and identify your device is entirely up to you.

I hope this explanation helps. Note that you could also create custom skill to control your device. There are a lot more examples of creating a custom skill. I've posted more custom skill information and code on [Github](http://github.com/rlisle)

Comment: can you explain or share code on, how do you make device discovery using alexa. Alexa doesn't with wifi or send direct signal to detect the devices. Instead it calls the internet (manufacturer server) and then get response about the device which is available around alexa. Do you have sample code or have exact logic on this.? I can see the block diagram mentioned but need details in depth...

Comment: Take a look at some of the published Alexa smart home skill examples, for instance this one by kvarma: https://github.com/krvarma/particle-alexa-smart-home-skill.
Look in the lambda.js code at the handleDiscovery method. In there he is defining kitchen bedroom lights.

Comment: Any examples about `Custom Skill`, run `Discovery` flow ?

Comment: I am also interested to know Custom Skill with Discovery flow